# Rewarding a badge for creating a tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges, badge-request, tag-creation

I think there could be a badge for creating a new tag. Since creating a tag would require 1.5k reputation, i think it might make sense to have at least a bronze tag for this. This would encourage people to ask questions in their domain which haven't been explored before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's already a silver [**Taxonomist**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist) badge for creating a tag that ends up getting used by at least 50 questions.

Comment: Yeah but that is for 50 questions. IF that might be the case then why not allow creating a tag when you reach say a score of 100 and if its not too popular in the next say 30 days then remove the new tag.

Comment: @lokoko: Trust me, just because it's a 1.5k user doesn't mean they create *good* tags. We actively destroy newly created ***misspelled*** tags all the time. So no, *just* creating a tag is not worthy of a badge, because all you have to do is literally type something in. The minimum question parameter is there to prevent abuse and ensure it's a *real* topic. Otherwise our system would be cluttered with unused tags waiting to be deleted by the system.

Comment: If we could have a badge for creating 2 accounts on stack exchange then i think we could give one to this :) I do get the point of spamming tags but still.

Comment: Dude, 1/2 to 2/3 of all new tags created every single day on SO end up getting nuked because they are *awful*.  New tag creation is not something we want to *promote*.

Comment: @lokoko I remember several months ago there was a community event to clean up old tags ambiguous tags, I participated in this event by removing the 'vb' tag and adding 'vba', 'vb6' or 'vb.net'. Less, more defined tags are much more useful as opposed to tags with < 50 answers.